# Jackson = $$son: pun or topical reference

Tags: quotes, history, homophones, puns

Alfred Bester's short story *The Demolished Man* (the original version serialized in Galaxy magazine in 1952, not the novel published in 1963) may have been the first instance of SMS-speak, featuring characters named “T8” (for “Tate”) and “$$son” (for Jackson).

Wait, how is “$$son” short for “Jackson”?

Randall Garrett, who wrote a review in verse using similar shortcuts (such as “Mr. Hassop has gone in2 th@ mor* his hide” — pronounce * as “asterisk”), has this to say:

> Also, there’s a character in the original called “$$son.” Now, I could have sworn
>   that was “Dollarson” and I wrote the verse accordingly. But when the book came out, it was
>   spelled “Jackson.”
>
> “Obscure, Alfie,” says I.
>
> “That’s why I changed it,” says he.

(from the introduction to said review in the collection *Takeoff!*, by Randall Garrett, Donning, 1979.)

Unfortunately Garrett does not reveal the connection. What is it?

(I realize the answer may or may not be on-topic, since it could be a reference to then-current events rather than a pun.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money:

> ...the $20 bill [can be referred to] as a "double sawbuck," **or a "Jackson"**

Comment: But that is quite a different building pattern from T8 for Tate. How do you derive the 20 from $$son, and why is the son repeated? To point to Jackson?

Comment: I think that's why the reviewer said it's pretty darn obscure...and why the author changed it to "Jackson" in the book version.

Comment: Since the term is slang, I imagine that people would readily abbreviate it in common usage, especially in the plural. For example: `Spare me two Jacks?` would be used to mean `Can you lend me $40?` If that is the case, the double `$` would indicate the plural "Jacks".